# Rails form_for with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having issues with routing a rails app to use a new and edit form.
The routes use the username within the URL.

```
               lists GET    /lists(.:format)                         lists#index
                     POST   /user/:username/lists(.:format)          lists#create
            new_list GET    /user/:username/lists/new(.:format)      lists#new
           edit_list GET    /user/:username/lists/:id/edit(.:format) lists#edit
                list GET    /user/:username/lists/:id(.:format)      lists#show
                     PATCH  /user/:username/lists/:id(.:format)      lists#update
                     PUT    /user/:username/lists/:id(.:format)      lists#update
                     DELETE /user/:username/lists/:id(.:format)      lists#destroy
                root GET    /                                        static#welcome
           show_user GET    /user/:id(.:format)                      users#show
```

My routes.rb-

```
  get 'lists', to: 'lists#index', as: :lists, via: 'get'

  scope 'user/:username' do
      resources :lists, except: [:index]
  end
```

My shared form, for use with updating and creating-

```
<%= form_for [@user, @list], url: list_path(@user, @list) do |f| %>
```

Using the above settings, I can edit lists correctly, but if I navigate to lists#new, I get the following error-

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lists", :id=>nil, :username=>"test"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

If I pluralize the path in my form to be `url: lists_path(@user, @list)`, then the `new` page will now load, but when trying to create I get the below error-

```
No route matches [POST] "/lists.test"
```

How can I fix these routes so I can use the same shared form for both edits and creating?

Adding controller code-

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
      @lists = List.all
  end

  def show
  end

  # GET /lists/new
  def new
    @list = List.new
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  end


  def create
    @list = current_user.lists.new(list_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @list.save
        format.html { redirect_to list_path(@list.user.username, @list.id), notice: 'List was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @list.update(list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to list_path(@list.user.username, @list.id), notice: 'List was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to lists_url, notice: 'List was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_list
      @list = List.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:name, :category, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: How flexible are you with changing your routes?

Comment: `form_for` url builder will know if `@list` is a new record. Post your controller code please, and the rest of that view code, it might not be the form that is erroring.

Comment: Try removing the `url:` key altogether - the form_for method generates the src and the method of the form based on the `@list` - it'll post to lists (create) or patch to list (update) depending on the @list instance variable.

Comment: @Swards if I remove that url key, it gives the following error due to my scoped routing - ``undefined method `user_list_path' for #<#<Class:0x9a1bcc8>:0x8bed980>``

@BroiSatse I'm open as long as the format is generally the same, in that the username will be somewhere in the URL before the list id.

Comment: OK, that's because the 'scope' is on the routes.  Curious - why did you do scope instead of nested resources? ie -  `resources :users, only: :none do resources :lists end`.  You can look for the user_id in the lists controller the same way you're currently looking for username.

Comment: @Swards its probably to make it look nice for the user.

Comment: @MajorMajor this is a tricky problem there are many solutions, none of which i personally like. 1. Override the [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) method on your users model. 2. Check if `@list` is a `new_record?` and output the require helper. 3. Build all the routes to lists manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - Change the :url value in the form_for to `[[@list], :username => @user.username]`

Like so:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @list], url: [[@list], :username => @user.username] do |f| %>
```